# python PIL save image different size original

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I´m working on a project with PIL in python.
Simply by opening and saving an image makes the output image bigger (in Bytes) than the original, maintaining the same resolution, and i don´t know why...

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("photo.png")
img.save("photo2.png", "PNG")
```

[result from code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Mba.png)

Does any one have any idea why this happens? i need them to be exactly the same.

Comment: You didn't share your input image for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

PNG is a compressed lossless format. The original image was probably saved with different compression settings.

Looking at the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png) you could try:

```
img.save("photo2.png", "PNG", optimize=True)
```

or

```
img.save("photo2.png", "PNG", compress_level=9)
```

By default, `compress_level=6` is used.

Note that the `optimize` option *includes* setting the compression level to 9. But it also tries to find optimal encoder settings.

Comment: it did not solve the problem...
Indeed the original image must have different compression settings, not available in the Python Imaging Library (PIL).
What i did was using photo2.png as the original...
ty any awy

Comment: The `libpng` library has losts of possible settings other than compression. PIL can probably not use all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't change the image, otherwise the size would be different. If you don't change the image why don't you just copy it?

```
shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```