# How to properly encode and decode base64 image to get exact same image with python?

Tags: python, image, base64

I am missing something during the operation because the images are not the same (though it is visually not possible to see a difference).

MWE:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.jpg')
buffered = BytesIO()
image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
image_content = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(buffered.getvalue())

image_decoded = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(image_content.decode())))

print(image == image_decoded)
# return False
print(np.array(image).sum() == np.array(image_decoded).sum())
# return False
```

Comment: When you `image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")` the data in `buffered` is already different than your opened image.

Comment: @Idlehands can you explain me please?

Comment: If you tried to `img2 = Image.open(buffered)` after the `image.save` line immediately, you will already notice `img != img2`.  I have a feeling that when it tries to save it's not necessarily being saved in the same manner as the original, hence the difference.

Comment: Perhaps a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642690/python-pil-save-image-different-size-original

Comment: @Idlehands you were right, opening the image with Pil already altered the binary content, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted that out thanks to @Idlehands comment. `Image.open(...)` already altered the binary content.

A working solution:

```
import base64

from PIL import Image

with open('image_name.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    image_byte = image_file.read()
    image_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(image_byte)

with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as image_file:
    image_file.write(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(image_base64))


image = Image.open('image_name.jpg')
image_decoded = Image.open('test.jpg')
image == image_decoded
```