# Opening an image in python and resaving it with the same resolution and dpi

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm learning some very basic steganography using python.

So far, I've been opening the file using:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file_location = '...'.png

rgb_data = np.array(plt.imread(file_location))

...
manually or otherwise edit some RGB values
...

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(rgb_data)
plt.savefig('image.jpg', dpi=96)
```

*Note: In the above code, I've left out the particular edits I've been doing to the image. This is because I don't think they are part of my issue. Even if I make no changes at all, and just load then resave the image, I still encounter the issues below.*

I've encountered three issues trying to save images using matplotlib in this way.

**1. Getting the dpi to match**
I'm not certain how to get the dpi of the output image to automatically match the dpi of the read image.

**2. Getting the resolution to match**
The resolutions of the input and output image by default don't match. Even if I manually match the dpi of the two images, they still don't have matching resolutions.

**3. Getting the file sizes to match**
My end goal is to produce an image that has the same dpi, resolution, and file size as the original. That way, when I start playing around with the RGB values, it should superficially appear to be the exact same image.

**My question is how to save the file so the dpi and resolution (and presumably by extension the size...) of the output image match the input?**

Of course, the number of pixels in the image, along with the dpi, should fix the resolution. However, it appears as though the output image is saved with a white border surrounding it, which is throwing off the resolution too.

Solutions using any python library are appreciated. However, edits to the existing code are preferable. Since I use matplotlib a lot, it would be useful to know how to circumvent this problem in the future too. Your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.save(...)` will save a Matplotlib figure. If you want to use only Matplotlib, please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218608/scipy-savefig-without-frames-axes-only-content).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file_location = '...'.png

rgb_data = np.array(plt.imread(file_location))

# modify your image

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)

h, w, _ = rgb_data.shape
fig.set_size_inches(w, h)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

ax.imshow(rgb_data, aspect='auto')

path_to_save = "..."
fig.savefig(path_to_save)
```

The output image should match the input image.

But I think it will be better to save your image by using pillow.

```
import PIL.Image as Image
import numpy as np

file_location = "img.png"
path_to_save = "out.png"

img = Image.open(file_location) 
rgb_data = np.array(img)

# modify your image

rgb_data = Image.fromarray(rgb_data)
rgb_data.save(path_to_save, format="PNG") 
# you can also specify dpi, quality and etc.
# for example rgb_data.save(path_to_save, format="PNG", dpi=(300,300))
```

(Note: it is possible that due to compression settings of the input image size, the output size will be different, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642690/python-pil-save-image-different-size-original))

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much Mikhail! This answers my question with nice detail and the related posts were very helpful too.